# Elements of form is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I try to set the focus on the first editable field in a form of my choice by the following code in javascript:

```
function setFocus( id) {
    var currentDialog = document.forms[id];

    for( i = 0; i < currentDialog.elements.length; i++) {
        if (!currentDialog.elements[i].disabled) {
            currentDialog.elements[i].focus();
            i = currentDialog.elements.length;
        }
    }
}
```

It finds the form but the elements seem to be undefined so the focus is not set. The weird thing is that I even get no error. In Firbug it shows me that elements is filled but the access to the property is not working.

I believe it is a small nasty error in my code but I can't find it. Has anybody of you an idea?

Comment: Could you put up a http://jsfiddle.net/ example and specify which field you want to focus on? Also as a side note, you can use the command 'break' to get out of a for loop whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the useful hint with the "break". I found out that there were two mistakes I'll explain in the next answer because that was one part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentDialog.elements.length; i++)
```

and not `for (i = 0; i < currentDialog.elements.length; i++)`

I think this was the mistake

Comment: It's clearly better to declare the varible locally, but the loop works just fine with a global variable too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was the first part of the answer. The other was hidden in the form itself. The first fields in the form were of type hidden which are not disabled. So the if block is executed and the loop ended with the attemp to focus a hidden field. Sometimes I feel my blindness blending.